# Custom audit log message send from Oracle DB version 12c to SIEM via syslog

Tags: security, oracle12c, audit

i need to send audit log from Oracle DB version 12c to my SIEM via syslog on IBM AIX. The problem is it not include the information i need. For exp:

> <134>Mar  4 11:00:25 Message forwarded from abc: Oracle Audit[5374348]: LENGTH : '494' ACTION :[344] '9'),chartorowid('AAAAJCAABAAAA+nABn'),chartorowid('AAAAJCAABAAAA+nABv'),chartorowid('AAAAJCAABAAAisBAAP'),chartorowid('AAAAJCAABAAAisBAC9'),chartorowid('AAAAJCAABAAAisBADQ'),chartorowid('AAAAJCAABAAAisDACn'),chartorowid('AAAAJCAABAAAisEABG'),chartorowid('AAAAJCAABAAAisEABf'),chartorowid('AAAAJCAABAAAisEABn'),chartorowid('AAAAJCAABAAAisEACb'),' DATABASE USER:[3] 'SYS' PRIVILEGE :[4] 'NONE' CLIENT USER:[0] '' CLIENT TERMINAL:[7] 'UNKNOWN' STATUS:[1] '0' DBID:[10] '2346730987'

It not have the information about source IP which really needed to parsing log for security purpose. Is there possile for us to modify and include some information that we need into it ? Thank!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to modify the information generated by Oracle's internal auditing. If you need to supplement the data going to your SIEM, then either

1. the SIEM tool needs to generate SQL queries to the audit trail
   and any other necessary tables within the database, instead of
   relying on syslog; or
2. you need to write a custom PL/SQL function to run the
   appropriate queries and use UTL_FILE to write the output to an
   external log file that the SIEM can read.

That said, it looks like your log sample is an audit of SYS actions, which may not even exist in the internal audit trail depending on your specific setup and version. If that is the case, what you see is all there is.

Comment: Thank you for reply, yes i has try to use jdbc and access to the table inside the DB and get the logs but sadly our DB team tell me that it impact to the DB availability. Can i ask you: The AUDIT and NOAUDIT command, can we use it on a group of user ? Because in DB there is a lot of user. If typing the AUDIT command for each user isn't the best idea. THanks

Comment: Depending on your version of Oracle and how auditing is implemented, you can audit certain things on all users, but Oracle doesn't really have "groups" like an operating system would. All "normal" auditing is generally written to database tables and would require SQL access, too. I believe I read that Oracle was deprecating the ability to write audit trails to OS files, and the data written to OS log files has always been limited compared to what's in the DB tables.